# Кодировка в SMTP-сообщениях

Tags: c#, smtp, кодировка

Я получаю от Exchange-сервера письмо с кириллицей. Текст сообщения при отправлении - "**Hello, мир!**". Есть проблема при обработке это сообщения потому что:

1. кириллица ("**мир**") - передается в формате Quoted Printables, т.е. вид имеет примерно такой - "**=F1=E2=E3**"
2. При перекодировке из Quoted Printables в 1251  (чтобы рус. яз. отобразился нормально) теряется латинница.

Так я получаю русский язык из Quoted Printables:

```
public static string DecodeQuotedPrintables(string input, Encoding encoding)
    {
        var regex = new Regex(@"\=(?<Symbol>[0-9A-Z]{2})", RegexOptions.Multiline);
        var matches = regex.Matches(input);
        var bytes = new byte[matches.Count];

        for (var i = 0; i < matches.Count; i++)
        {
            bytes[i] = Convert.ToByte(matches[i].Groups["Symbol"].Value, 16);
        }

        return encoding.GetString(bytes);
    }
```

**Подскажите пожалуйста алгоритм, как, имея в строке латинницу и крилиицу конвертировать сообщение, чтобы сохранить оба языка?**

Comment: Напрямую SMTP обрабатываете или с помощью каких-то классов? Каких?

Comment: У меня есть закодированная строка , мне нужно без потерь извлечь из не кириллицу и латинницу

Comment: Вот такая `\=(?<Symbol>[0-9A-F]{2})|(?<Lit>.)` регулярка вам даст совпадения с именами Symbol и Lit, причем в одном захвате может быть только один из них. Если есть Lit то добавляете его к выходной строке, если нет - то код от Symbol. Только я бы все таки предложил простой побайтный разбор строки без всяких регулярок, оно явно быстрее будет

Comment: Практически так я  и сделал. оформите как ответ, я отмечу

Answer (score 1):

Идешь по строке, от символа к символу. Рассматриваешь каждый символ. Если код символа имеет значение: с 33 по 60; или с 62 по 126; или 32 или 9, то кладешь этот код в байтовый буфер. Если это символ "равно" ("="), то после него может идти либо перевод строки (то есть "\r\n"), либо двузначное шестнадцатеричное число. Если после "=" идет перевод строки, то пропускаешь этот перевод строки. Если после "=" идет шестнадцатеричное число, то кладешь его значение в байтовый буфер. В конце, переводишь полученный байтовый буфер в строку в соответствие с кодировкой. Примерно так:

```
static string FromQuotePrintable(string s, Encoding e) {
      using (var ms = new MemoryStream(s.Length)) {
        for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; ++i) {
          byte c = (byte)s[i];
          if (c >= 33 && c <= 60 || c >= 62 && c <= 126 || c==' ' || c=='\t') {
            ms.WriteByte(c);
            continue;
          }
          if (c == '=') {
            i += 2;
            if (s[i - 1] == '\r' && s[i] == '\n') {
              continue;
            }
            ms.WriteByte(byte.Parse(s.Substring(i - 1, 2), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber));
          }
        }
        return e.GetString(ms.GetBuffer(), 0, (int)ms.Length);
      }
    }
```

В этом коде нет проверки на несоответствие кодировке Quote Printable. Так что если входная строка будет ей не соответствовать, то могут происходить разные ошибки: выход за пределы строки, ошибка при переводе из шестнадцатеричной строки в байт и другие. 
Описание кодировки здесь: http://kunegin.com/ref2/email/mime03.htm

В принципе по скорости и памяти было бы эффективнее самому переводить из 2-х шестнадцатеричных символов в байт, без "выгрызания" подстроки. Это чуть сложнее.